# Why does `git rebase --continue` fail with gitmodules error?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

I created a branch named lab based on master. Months later, I tried to rebase the lab branch based on master. First there is one .gitignore conflict; after solving it, I ran `git rebase --continue`, but it failed again and this time there is no help info telling me how to continue with this rebase. How to rebase lab branch based on master?

```
git rebase --continue
Applying: start edit
Applying: a
fatal: mode change for .gitmodules, which is not in current HEAD
Repository lacks necessary blobs to fall back on 3-way merge.
Cannot fall back to three-way merge.
Patch failed at 0002 a
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   f:/testxxx/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Answer (score 1):

`.gitmodules` exists on one branch and not the other. Look at the patch file and see which, and then use git add or git rm to decide if you want a `.gitmodules` files as a result of the rebase or not.

Comment: i cannot remove .gitmodules on master branch, because i can only modify on my own fork, if i rm .gitmodules on master branch, i cannot pull update from remote repo then :( the problem is still how to rebase my lab branch based on master branch?

Answer (score 0):

Try running rebase with the --merge modifier

```
git rebase --merge branchname
```